# Represent zero-width space as a string constant

Tags: php, string, utf-16

How do I represent the zero-width space character (hex UTF-16 200b) in a PHP string constant in my source file?  i.e. I want to add this character to a string in a test case like

```
$str = 'test' . $zwcHere . 'test2';
```

In C I could just use something like

```
char c = '\x200b';
```

Info on ZWC: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm

Comment: cHao's answer wasn't directly what I was looking for in that I wasn't looking for how to output it to the browser (I would just use HTML entity), but the string example given was what I needed anyway.  To answer directly:

    $str = 'some text' . "\xE2\x80\x8B" . 'whatever else';

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP's "characters" are 8-bit.  If you want to output a character with a code higher than 128, you'll need to specify an encoding that supports that character, then output the codes that that encoding requires.

If you set UTF-8 encoding, for example, you'd print `"\xE2\x80\x8B"`.

Of course, if this is HTML, you can typically use the HTML entity ref `&#x200b;` as well, which wouldn't require changing the page's encoding.