# Remove new lines from beginning and end of string in php using trim

Tags: php, newline, trim

I was under the impression that the [trim command in PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php), if you leave out the second parameter that specifies specific characters remove not only white spaces but also new lines from the beginning (and end) of a string.

> This function returns a string with whitespace stripped from the
> beginning and end of str. Without the second parameter, trim() will
> strip these characters:
>
> " " (ASCII 32 (0x20)), an ordinary space. "\t" (ASCII 9 (0x09)), a
> tab. "\n" (ASCII 10 (0x0A)), a new line (line feed). "\r" (ASCII 13
> (0x0D)), a carriage return. "\0" (ASCII 0 (0x00)), the NUL-byte.
> "\x0B" (ASCII 11 (0x0B)), a vertical tab.

However, I am applying it to a string that has some new lines at the beginning resulting from deleted text and it is leaving the following:

```
\u200b\n\nTHE TEXT I WANT STARTS HERE. I WANT TO GET RID OF EVERTHING BEFORE WORD THE
```

The reason I'm trying to use trim is because I want to preserve new lines and formating in the middle of the text as it may be broken into paragraphs. I just want to trim it at the edges.

Am I wrong that trim is supposed to remove line breaks and new lines at the beginning and end of the string?  What is the proper way to remove new lines as in the above?

Comment: _“Am I wrong that trim is supposed to remove line breaks at the beginning and end of the string?”_ - no, you are just wrong in assuming you _had_ linebreaks at the _begin_ of `\u200b\n\nTHE TEXT …` - `\u200b` is not a line break, and not part of the white space character lists that trim will remove, that you quoted yourself from the manual.

Comment: \u200b is zero width space and \n is a new line..\n is one of the things mentioned in the manual.  What code are you recommending?

Comment: _“\n is one of the things mentioned in the manual”_ - yes, but it is not at the _beginning_, if it has other stuff _before_ it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add ZERO LENGTH SPACE character (\u200b) to the list of characters to be stripped and then it works as you expect.

```
$ws = " \t\n\r\0\x0B\u200b";
$s = trim
(
 "\u200b\n\nTHE TEXT I WANT STARTS HERE. I WANT TO GET RID OF EVERTHING BEFORE WORD THE",
 $ws
);
echo $s;
```

It may be a good idea to add the NO-BREAK SPACE character (\xA0) too.

Comment: Your example works so I'm marking correct. In my specific  case, it is still not working..I'm suspecting there are some hidden characters I can't see. The characters I gave in the question are what appear after the string is json encoded. If I just echo the string out, it shows new lines. Do you know a fool proof way to  see hidden characters?

Comment: I would use bin2hex.

Comment: And btw please be very careful about character encoding.

Comment: what is character encoding?

Comment: FYI, I was able to strip out the characters using: $string = str_replace(array("\n\r", "\n", "\r"), "", $string);//GETS RID OF new lines
$string = preg_replace( '/[\x{200B}-\x{200D}]/u', '', $string);//GETS rid of zero width space. Still working on how to do this with trim.

Comment: Well, I would keep preg_replace. It is more expensive, yes, but unless you call it many thousands of times in a loop this does not matter really.

Comment: And I would further suggest that you rework the regular expression to care about string start and string end and do it all in one go. Here it is:  
`/(^[\r\n\t\xA0 \x{200B}-\x{200D}]+)|([\r\n\t\xA0 \x{200B}-\x{200D}]+$)/ug`

Answer (score 1):

Caution! The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62877977/2740514) does not remove zero-width spaces. Instead it removes the individual characters `\`, `u`, `2`, `0`, `b`.

If anyone wants to remove an [actual zero-width space](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17334027) at the beginning or end of a string using `trim()`, this is the correct way to do it:

```
$trimmed = trim(
    $str,
    "\xE2\x80\x8B" // zero-width character
);
```